# how to redirect in other page when browser close event called

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect in another page when browser is closed. My code is following:

```
<script language="Javascript">  
var needToConfirm = true;
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit(){
  if (needToConfirm){
    my_window = window.open ("1.html","mywindow1","status=1,width=350,height=150");

    return "You have attempted to leave this page. If you have made any changes "
          +"to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be "
          +"lost. Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
  }
}
```

But when I am clicking on close button of browser, I am seeing an **system confirmation message** and I am also not getting pop up page opening in mozilla. How will i resolve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code excerpt from [this](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/exit_confirmation.php) page.

```
function goodbye(e) {
if(!e) e = window.event;
//e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
e.cancelBubble = true;
e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog

//e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
```

Comment: What and where i should i write code to open a pop page (page.html).I don't want to appear confirm alert box, instead i want to open my pop window or redirect into other location. Thanks

Comment: i really don't understand how this solves (or: should solve) Ajay_Kumars problem... where is the popup gone? (and _opening the popup_ was the problem, not _showing the dialog_)

Answer (score 0):

short answer:

your code works perfectly if you wouldn't have blocked it.

long answer:

[this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-popup-example4.html) is a working example - and it's almost the same like yours (take a look at the sourcecode).

but: this works only if you're generally disabling the popup-blocker in FF (or create a rule to allow popups from that URL).

i'm sure the reason your code isn't working is the activated popup-blocker, wich shows this nice, yellow "site tries to open a popup"-warning wich isn't shown to you because the site is closed (so, you can't klick on "allow popups from this site").